# Insert custom record in oracle TABLE-VARRAY

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to manually insert custom `BLOB` files into a local table variable. I want to use it like a `VARRAY` but I'm using a `TABLE` type since I don't know the max number of files.

This is the code for my package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_pkg AS
    TYPE rec_headers IS RECORD
    (
        file1   BLOB := EMPTY_BLOB(),
        file2   BLOB := EMPTY_BLOB()
    );
    TYPE tab_headers IS TABLE OF rec_headers;
END my_pkg;
```

And this is my PL\SQL block:

```
DECLARE
    p_headers my_pkg.tab_headers;

    p_my_file1  BLOB := EMPTY_BLOB();
    p_my_file2  BLOB := EMPTY_BLOB();
BEGIN
    p_headers := my_pkg.tab_headers();

    /* Process that fills p_my_file1 and p_my_file2 */

    p_headers.EXTEND;

    p_headers(1) := my_pkg.rec_headers(p_my_file1, p_my_file2);
END;
/
```

I'm getting the following error

```
PLS-00222: no function with name 'REC_HEADERS' exists in this scope
```

I'm assuming is because `rec_headers` is of type `RECORD` so I tried to change it to `OBJECT` but then it complains that is not supported inside the package.

I can't create the `OBJECT` type outside the package since I don't have the privileges (and I will not get them).

There is still a way of achieving it just using variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to reference the fields of the record directly rather than trying to use a constructor.

```
DECLARE
    p_headers my_pkg.tab_headers;

    p_my_file1  BLOB := EMPTY_BLOB();
    p_my_file2  BLOB := EMPTY_BLOB();
BEGIN
    p_headers := my_pkg.tab_headers();

    /* Process that fills p_my_file1 and p_my_file2 */

    p_headers.EXTEND;

    p_headers(1).file1 := p_my_file1;
    p_headers(1).file2 := p_my_file2;
END;
/
```